# How to add my custom phtml to product page magento 2?

Tags: product, magento2

In magento 2,

I want to add my custom phtml to product view page how can i add that

i want to add that phtml as tab like review or Description.

i am trying this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="3columns"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Example\Examples\Block\Question" name="example.tab" template="Example_Examples::success.phtml">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

its give 404 error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try This code.

You have to add `group="detailed_info"` For Create tab like review or detail

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Example\Examples\Block\Question" name="example.tab" template="Example_Examples::success.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Title</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I also in a same need. And I'm very new to M2. Please can you share the other steps I should follow to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try below code,,Your phtml file content will display near social icon,,You can change `referenceBlock name` if you want to change position

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>        
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.social">
            <block class="Example\Examples\Block\Question" name="example.tab" template="Example_Examples::success.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i want to add that phtml as tab like review or Description